# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_FUNCTION in DB_driver.php on line 33

Tags: php, mysql

Got a program that a coder designed but wasn't will to help setup it up. I am getting this error when trying to connect the code to the database

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting T_FUNCTION in \system\database\DB_driver.php on line 33

I have double checked the hostname,username,password, and database name but with no victory.

```
var $hostname;      = 'localhost';
var $username;      = 'pepadmin';
var $password;      = '******';
var $database;      = 'databasetest';
var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
var $dbprefix       = '';
var $char_set       = 'utf8';
var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
var $autoinit       = TRUE; // Whether to automatically initialize the DB
var $swap_pre       = '';
var $port           = '';
var $pconnect       = FALSE;
var $conn_id        = FALSE;
var $result_id      = FALSE;
var $db_debug       = FALSE;
var $benchmark      = 0;
var $query_count    = 0;
var $bind_marker    = '?';
var $save_queries   = TRUE;
var $queries        = array();
var $query_times    = array();
var $data_cache     = array();
var $trans_enabled  = TRUE;
var $trans_strict   = TRUE;
var $_trans_depth   = 0;
var $_trans_status  = TRUE; // Used with transactions to determine if a rollback should occur
var $cache_on       = FALSE;
var $cachedir       = '';
var $cache_autodel  = FALSE;
var $CACHE; // The cache class object

// Private variables
var $_protect_identifiers   = TRUE;
var $_reserved_identifiers  = array('*'); // Identifiers that should NOT be escaped

// These are use with Oracle
var $stmt_id;
var $curs_id;
var $limit_used;
```

Comment: which is the line `33`..???

Comment: what's with all the "var"?

Comment: This looks like a configuration file. You need to post this file: `DB_driver.php`

Comment: which version of codeigniter do you use?

Comment: Please always respond to people who help you. This is an old question, and if you no longer need answers, it is a good idea to post a comment to that effect. I'll try to close it, as the answers below were based on a misunderstanding of the code you provided - this was part of a `class`, right? The `var` statements are a legacy way of defining publicly-accessible properties (I think from PHP4, so very old indeed!).

Comment: This question should be put on hold because (a) the answers provided were based on too little code being provided, (b) it has been abandoned, and (c) it is probably too localised to be of value to future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first off, you probably don't need all those `var` declarations. also, you are terminating these lines with the semicolon before you even define them.

```
var $hostname;      = 'localhost';
var $username;      = 'pepadmin';
var $password;      = '******';
var $database;      = 'databasetest';
```

vs what you intended

```
$hostname      = 'localhost';
$username      = 'pepadmin';
$password      = '******';
$database      = 'databasetest';
```

Answer (score 0):

remove semicolen after the variables try this

```
    var $hostname      = 'localhost';
    var $username     = 'pepadmin';
    var $password     = '******';
    var $database      = 'databasetest';
```

Answer (score 0):

No need var and should not use semicolon before initializing variable. Remove the marked chars.

`var` $hostname`;`      = 'localhost';

`var` $username`;`      = 'pepadmin';

`var` $password`;`      = '******';

`var` $database`;`      = 'databasetest';